# IoSetCompletionRoutine does not call CompletionRoutine at the first time

Tags: c++, windows, kernel, driver, windows-kernel

I have keyboard driver and am registering CompletionRoutine using this code:

```
NTSTATUS DispatchRead(PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject, PIRP Irp)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(DeviceObject);
    
    IoCopyCurrentIrpStackLocationToNext(Irp);
    IoSetCompletionRoutine(Irp, ReadComplete, NULL, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE);

    pendingkey++;


    IoCallDriver(((PDEVICE_EXTENSION)DeviceObject->DeviceExtension)->LowerKbdDevice, Irp);

    return STATUS_PENDING;
}
```

And there is my CompletionRoutine:

```
NTSTATUS ReadComplete(PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject, PIRP Irp, PVOID Context)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(DeviceObject);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(Context);

    CHAR* KeyFlag[4] = {"KeyDown", "KeyUp", "E0", "E1"};

    PKEYBOARD_INPUT_DATA Keys = (PKEYBOARD_INPUT_DATA)Irp->AssociatedIrp.SystemBuffer;
    int structnum = (ULONG)Irp->IoStatus.Information / sizeof(KEYBOARD_INPUT_DATA);

    if (Irp->IoStatus.Status == STATUS_SUCCESS) {
        for (int i = 0; i < structnum; i++)
        {
            DbgPrintEx(0, 0, "the scan code is %x (%s)\n", Keys[i].MakeCode, KeyFlag[Keys[i].Flags]);
        }
    }

    if (Irp->PendingReturned) {
        IoMarkIrpPending(Irp);
    }

    pendingkey--;
    return Irp->IoStatus.Status;
}
```

When i run driver at the first time and press any key, CompletionRoutine calls only for **Key Up** event, and not for **Key Down**. But when i press some key next time, i get both **Key Up** and **Key Down** events. So, can`t understand reason of this behavior